# Difference between msoGraphic and msoPicture in Powerpoint shape types

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When extracting shape type on PowerPoint slide using VBA the result is either **msoGraphic** or **msoPicture** for an Image shape.
What are the differences between these two types?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When working with VBA you'll want to get familiar with the documentation, here is the main page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/, here is the page you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.type

Comment: MS' documentation doesn't help much in this case. msoPicture is a shape that's a raster or vector image (e.g. JPG/PNG/BMP or EMF/WMF respectively).  msoGraphic is a newly introduced type. The new Icons are msoGraphic types.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  Before introducing msoGraphic, is it possible that PPT icons were typed as msoPicture ?

Comment: @David Doubtful, but if so, it would have been for a very brief while. Icons are a rather new feature and PPT treats them differently from normal pictures (allows recoloring foreground/background, for example).  However, you might well have icon images from a source other than PPT's Insert | Icon gallery. These would be msoPictures, in all probability.